# Exponent log inequalites

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm stuck in trying to figure out why this inequality is true:
$$ n^{\log^4 n} \leq 2^{\log^5 n} ~~~~~~ \text{for} ~n>2$$
(Here $\log$ denotes the base $2$ logarithm). I'm sure there's some simple little algebraic trick but I'm just not seeing it. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Just take log both sides it becomes  $\log^5 n $

Comment: Thus we have equality, right?

Comment: Yes, lhs = rhs right

Answer (score 1):

$$n^{\log^4 n} \leq 2^{\log^5 n} $$
$$2^{\log(n)\log^4 n} \leq 2^{\log^5 n} $$
$$2^{\log^5 n} \leq 2^{\log^5 n} $$
They are equals..
or 
$$n^{\log^4 n} \leq 2^{\log^5 n}=2^{\log(n)\log^4 n}=(2^{\log(n)})^{\log^4 n}=n^{\log^4 n}$$